# Accessing private members of class instance

Tags: typescript

I came across the following point and could not understand this completely. The statement goes like this (emphasis mine):

> The private access modifier in the constructor automatically assigns the parameter
> to this (this.file and so on), and sets its visibility to private, meaning that
> code within a Position instance can read and write to it, but code outside of a
> Position instance can’t. **Different instances of Position can access each other’s
> private members**; instances of any other class—even a subclass of Position—
> can’t.

Can anyone explain me what it really mean? With example.

Comment: I am aware that private members/fields cannot be accessed externally, but this is not the answer of my question.

Comment: It would be nice if *you* had an example with whatever `Position` might be, but [here is a made-up example](https://tsplay.dev/NBd9bW). Other instances of a class can access an instance's private members. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer post explaining; if not, what's missing for you?

Comment: I will write an answer when I get the chance; I have to go to sleep now so it will be in a number of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's [`private`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) members are considered *class*-private, not *instance*-private.  Inside the body of a class, you are allowed to access the private members of *other instances* of the class.  That lets you do things like this:

```
class Foo {
    private bar: number;
    constructor(bar: number) { this.bar = bar; }
    lessThan(otherFoo: Foo) {
        return this.bar < otherFoo.bar
        // -------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
const f0 = new Foo(0);
const f1 = new Foo(1);
console.log(f0.lessThan(f1)) // true
console.log(f1.lessThan(f0)) // false
```

In the above, `otherFoo.bar` is only possible because `bar` is private to `Foo`, not to `otherFoo`.

---

Among other things, this means that outside `Foo`, you can see that `bar` *exists*, but you cannot access its value.  If you couldn't see that it existed, you'd be allowed to do the following dangerous thing:

```
class Qux {
    private x = "abc";
    y = 123;
    method(otherQux: Qux) { 
      console.log(otherQux.x.toUpperCase()) 
    }
}

const q = new Qux();

q.method({
    y: 123,
    method: Qux.prototype.method
}) // runtime error
```

Here `Qux` has a private `x` property and a public `y` property and `method` method.  If outside of `Qux` you only saw `y` and `method`, then by [structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) you'd be allowed to treat `{y: 123, method: Qux.prototype.method}` as a valid value of `Qux`.  And then you'd get a runtime error because suddenly `otherQux` doesn't have the private member.

And since `x` is `private` you can't fix the above issue by adding `x` to your object:

```
q.method({
    x: "abc",
    y: 123,
    method: Qux.prototype.method
}) // compiler error,
// Property 'x' is private in type 'Qux' but not in type 
// '{ x: string; y: number; method: (otherQux: Qux) => void; }'.
```

So *that* means [the only way you can get an object to match `Foo` or `Qux` is to actually call their constructors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#private-and-protected-members-in-classes).  So one use of `private` properties is to enforce so-called [nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), where a value is only a `Qux` if it came from the `Qux` *class declaration*.  This differs from most of TypeScript, where only the *structure* of an object matters, not its declaration (see the link to "structural typing" above).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.4.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4CcCWAbmAC4Cm0ARmDgFzQB2ArgLYWk4Dc6mw89ExHI2DF4OABRVaDFmxwBKFNGIALPBAB0U6AF5K1DtAC+3DCFJQAKirD1x8VewTw6zxWkyfoOUsUY56ZTVNbQAeaAcVJ0QtalMvAHoE6ABaNPSM9IA+aAA9fILC-PiTE15+YmgAMwAGXQZSAHc4RHEa+S5ygWqARnr6Jpb4cR6O1C74cw0QeABzcVrpiwhrWwXRxSTlIVJxvghJ0mm59aWrGzta+U3kqrAQCF3x8ChoAEVGAA8UeNxCEnI3z0ACIwBRgMCuJ4AJ71HoAJgAzFDMMxfCp4AATeyOHAfT50fHuaATKYzeaRdj4jSfDSiACqWCw7AAwpBSOJrsZUGV9pUAI79Qb4zlcfkaNGqLHiDyYaF0BGIgA08UlGMxhK+GlwDgc0OZEvRWJ5N28jHoxDwaOg7BwYlQqHFaulsowBOgoPBwJVMIVSJ9qKNGveWp1omI+qOzsxJugW14zCweHMOBtODtOBVWwACnbmTgI9AAOSfIvQdTYfBEMjlwIR5nF-FliiMSr0By15SR6CoLZF5DQd0CfD0WaGeUyVjsQzRug4qJ4r6az6KHQ5AjwPCYwxGIsaIA)